# POST data to other URI with URL change in REST (POST and Redirect)

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I need to POST data and at the same time redirect to that URL in REST environment. I can do this for normal strings, but the requirement is to POST specific Object.

The way I do it for normal string is -

```
public Response homePage(@FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("passwordhash") String password) {
    return Response.ok(PreparePOSTForm(username)).build();
}

private static String PreparePOSTForm(String username)
{
    //Set a name for the form
    String formID = "PostForm";
    String url = "home";

    //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
    StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
    strForm.append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + 
                    formID + "\" action=\"" + url + 
                    "\" method=\"POST\">");

   strForm.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + "username" + 
                        "\" value=\"" + username + "\">");

    strForm.append("</form>");
    //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
    strScript.append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
    strScript.append("var v" + formID + " = document." + 
                        formID + ";");
    strScript.append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
    strScript.append("</script>");
    //Return the form and the script concatenated.
    //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
    return strForm.toString() + strScript.toString();
}
```

But this method is not sending Objects. I need a work around to send complex Objects. Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tichodroma I want to POST Object to REST URI, process it in the function and display HTML result with changed URL of used REST URI in browser.

Comment: @Bhagyashri I am already using '@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)' because it is returning HTML created by 'PreparePOSTForm' function. If there is any way to skip use of this function and directly call some functions to POST data to REST URI and change URL at the same time, it is always welcome..